# cant add to cart rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

my rails version is 5.0.5, i am currently developing an online store. i am following the steps on Agile web development (rails 5). i have followed the steps accordingly, i can create new products, edit products,and delete products, i am stuck at the stage where i am to add a product to cart(the "Add to cart" button shows) when i click "Add to cart" it gives me an error{cant find product with id}..........this is the error guys.

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\COMPUTER>cd desktop

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop>cd trial

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop\trial>cd depot

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop\trial\depot>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-22 17:44:40 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Rendering store/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."title" ASC
  Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (620.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1888ms (Views: 1385.1ms | ActiveRecord: 20.0ms)


Started POST "/line_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-22 17:46:14 +0100
Processing by LineItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"tysgjA3w3dfMA1ACBRWeigDDnDM9WDiwBDKotUwmXVVxVy0+msnR4gmkB3QV8qU8dKdLdnb5yEOS5FmdUs7LyQ=="}
  Cart Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (4.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (48.0ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2017-10-22 16:46:15.531901"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-22 16:46:15.531901"]]
   (108.0ms)  commit transaction
  Product Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 644ms (ActiveRecord: 180.0ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=):

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:29:in `create'
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (52.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (24.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (16.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (8928.0ms)
```

also below is the store(the default homepage that shows the products) view file.....

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> 

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1> 
<% cache @products do %>
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
<% cache @product do %>
<div class="entry"> 


<h3><%= product.title %></h3> 

<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class="price_line"> 

<span class="price"><%= number_to_currency (product.price) %></span> 

<%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path   %>
</div> 
</div> 
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

als below is the routes......

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  root 'store#index', as: 'store_index'

  resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

and below is the products model ......

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 

        validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true 
        validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01} 
        validates :title, uniqueness: true 
        validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: { 
            with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, 
            message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.' 
            } 




        has_many :line_items
        before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item




  #...
    private
     # ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
          def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
            unless line_items.empty?
             errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
                throw :abort
          end
    end
end
```

below is the carts model....

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end

def add_product (lineitem, product_id)
 current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
  if current_item
   current_item.quantity += 1 
else
   current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
     end 
     current_item 
 end
```

line items model....

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

application_record.rb........

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

carts controller....

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to carts_url, notice: 'Cart was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params.fetch(:cart, {})
    end
end

application controller.....
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

line items controller....

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find (params[:product_id])  

 @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)



   respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id)
    end
end
```

products controller...

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

store controller.....

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)

  end
end
```

Comment: Why do not you use strong parameters `line_item_params ` in create? Or use a breakpoint `byebug` or `pry` to see what you are receiving in the params.

Comment: i am a newbie, pls tell me how to use byebug or pry or how to use the line_ items_params to fix this problem. thanks Silviu M

Answer (score 3):

Your error is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=):`. This means that the controller doesn't know which product you want to add to the cart. This would be done by adding a `product_id` to the params of your `POST`.

In your view:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path   %>
```

The `line_items_path` probably isn't correct. You probably want `line_item_path(product_id: product.id)`. This will add the product's ID to the request and make it available when the controller tries to find the record here:

```
product = Product.find (params[:product_id])
```

Comment: Daniel westendorf i just did what you said i should do and i got an error..............this is the error.........

Answer (score 0):

In the view you have to send the correct product_id as suggested by [Daniel Westendorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518336/daniel-westendorf)

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path(product_id: product.id) %>
```

So, in this way when you create a new `LineItem` in `new` method of `LinesItemController`, you have it params

```
def new
  @line_item = LineItem.new(params[:product_id])
end
```

For using the debug mode you can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and you can use this [step_by_step installation](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3631-Debugging-using-ByeBug-Gem-in-Rails-5) guide.
[pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is another alternative.